# Configuring NTLDR so that I can dual boot without using grub?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-boot

I recovered my windows and in the process I lost the grub for ubuntu 9 . Now i want to change NTLDR so that i can dual boot. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what exactly you're proposing to do. If you want to restore GRUB so you can boot into Ubuntu again, follow the Ubuntu community documentation here: [Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows). If you want to use NTLDR to boot, with Ubuntu as an option in the list, follow this guide: [How to dual-boot Windows NT/2000/XP and Linux using NTLDR](http://jaeger.morpheus.net/linux/ntldr.php)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complicated procedure. If you do something wrong, you will have locked yourself out of your own computer. Recovery can be very time consuming. Be prepared for some hours of pain and horror!

**First,** please prepare some emergency boot media, such as your original Linux installation CD/DVD or USB pen drive. Some Linux distributions feature a recovery mode which will allow you either connect your installation to a boot prompt (i.e. chroot), which will in turn allow you to recovery your Linux boot ability (like: running grub-install from the chroot), or to boot from your installation directly (rare).

Another thing to prepare is [SuperGRUB](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) or [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) or [Clover](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/).

Also, have a Windows installation DVD or pen drive ready for recovery options.

Another thing to consider is having another PC that will allow you to at least search for some information on the internet. Ideally this is a PC as it will allow you also to copy some files to a USB pen drive if needed. Tablets like an iPad or an Android tablet will only work for internet research, not for such a copy operation.

**Next,** try out all your options: boot all your CDs/DVDs and USB pen drives on the computer where you intend to use them. Some may not work, so you have to decide wheather you re-try or wheather you skip using them.

**Then** (and only then) it is safe for you to start: [this Blog entry describes adding the Linux bootloader GRUB to the boot options on Windows 7](https://pw999.wordpress.com/2013/12/21/windows-7-linux-dualboot-using-bcd-instead-of-grub/). It may or may not work for later Windows versions. But, since `BCDEDIT` is used, the chances are very good that it also works on later version. But then, the described method uses a BIOS based boot, i.e. a partition boot sector, which will not make it work (that easy) under an EFI based system.

Here one can see how complicated booting has become over the years: we have BIOS based booting, i.e. using the Master Boot Record (MBR) and boot sectors. But we now also have (U)EFI based booting – (Universal) Extensible Firmware Interface, the successor of the ancient BIOS, using the EFI System Partition (ESP) and appropriate EFI executables. It makes a great difference if a system is 32-Bit-EFI or 64-Bit-EFI – the wrong architecture will not work. And then we have hybrid installations, because EFI systems often also feature a Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates the old BIOS boot behaviour using boot sectors. Thus, on EFI (with a CSM) you can boot in two ways: using the CSM and a boot sector or using the ESP and an EFI executable as the boot loader.

I myself am currently also trying to use the Windows boot loader to start GRUB. I use an EFI based system that boots two operating systems using the EFI loaders from the ESP. But Windows 7 is booted using the BIOS compatible EFI-CSM (compatibility support module, i.e. BIOS emulation under EFI). So Windows 7 is booted 1) via a hybrid MBR partition and 2) via the VBR from that partition. Now, booting Linux from this configuration makes everything more complex, as the Linux /boot partition resides on a non-hybrid GPT partition. (Why would I want to do this in the first place? Because with the CSM the VGA BIOS is also included for Linux to load the DRM, which is not present when booted using EFI only. Adding a second CSM boot options is also not without complications, leaving me with two options: using PC-GRUB started from a bootsector for both Windows and Linux, or booting Linux from within the Windows boot loader.)

In my specific case, it may well be that such a boot configuration is impossible to set up…

I know this isn't much help really, but – if you try it – **make sure to have a backup plan for booting your system.**
Good luck!

Comment: Can you include some of the relevant info from the link you included on adding GRUB to Win7 boot options? If the blog disappears the information will still be available that way.

Answer (score 1):

In BIOS mode (not UEFI!) the thing that would work with NTLDR is to setup GRUB for the MBR, but keep the original MBR in place and safe the modified MBR for GRUB to a file, and add this file to `boot.ini` for NTLDR.

The original source for this can be found [here](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/102).

The procedure:

1. Backup the original MBR. In Linux, do `dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/mbr_saved.bin bs=512 count=1` (as root, or with `sudo`)
   Naturally you will have to do this when Windows NTLDR and the original MBR are still present. Thus this would have to be done from a Linux LiveCD or similar (a USB thumb drive). Save this MBR to a safe place (a USB pen drive or similar) for later use!
2. Install Linux as usual, but don't select GRUB to install to the MBR! Instead let it reside in the boot sector of the linux partition or don't install it at all. Just make sure you have means to again boot into this Linux, at least via `chroot` from a LiveCD (or similar).
3. Now, booted into Linux (or chrooted), install GRUB manually to the MBR. Save this MBR, same as above, to a file (e.g. `grub2.mbr`) that you put in the root directory of your Windows installation (where NTLDR and boot.ini are, in Windows terms `C:\`).
4. Restore the original MBR, but without the partition table—because it will be modified after the Linux installation...
   `dd if=mbr_saved.bin of=/dev/sda bs=1 count=446`
   Make sure the Windows partition has the active or "bootable" flag using e.g. `fdisk`.
   An alternative is to use a Windows XP installation disc. In the *Rescue* options one can start a *command line prompt* ("Recovery Console" + logon to the installed Windows until you see the command line), where `fixmbr` should also restore the original MBR code without modifying the partition table.
5. Add the GRUB MBR file to boot.ini: `c:\grub2.mbr="GRUB2 Bootloader"`

NOTE: This will only work with NTLDR, so Windows NT up to Windows XP (NT 5.1). Since Vista, BootMgr is used and the described method will no longer work!